# How good is this 'UI Tour' in an app?

Tags: guidelines

I am creating a UI Tour for a desktop app and I am drawing inspiration from this:

[ui tour.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVO7PCwKLD35mmgQdGCoqapdwUMCTe5Y/view?usp=sharing)

I am wondering how good UX is this UI Tour. It doesn't tell the user how to proceed or exit and the way to do those is clicking a mouse button to proceed and press Esc key to exit. I am not sure if these are easy enough to figure out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's simple enough for almost any user to figure out how to use it.
I think this approach helps keeping the user focused on the actual tour

but adding a skip button will also be a plus.